# How to get the value that the user chose from a UIPickerView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I want to take the value that the user selected from 2 different pickerViews and display that value in a textField

```
let drivingGear = ["1", "12", "36", "60", "84"]

    let boxVal = chooseDrivingGear
    let boxVal2 = chooseDrivenGear1
    let newVal = boxVal / boxVal2
    resultBox1.text = newVal
```

However I couldnt get that to work so I'm now trying this:

```
@IBAction func chooseBox1Pressed(_sender: UIButton) {
     sender.isHidden = true
     if chooseDrivingGear.isHidden {
         chooseDrivingGear.isHidden = false
      }


      if chooseDrivingGear[row] == "1" {
          let v1 = 1
}
```

but chooseDrivingGear[row] shows this error: use of unresolved identifier 'row'

(My other code for pickerview) UPDATE:

```
//first picker view
        chooseDrivingGear.isHidden = true
        chooseDrivingGear.delegate = self
        chooseDrivingGear.dataSource = self
        chooseDrivingGear.tag = 0

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            chooseBox1.setTitle(drivingGear[row], for: .normal)
            chooseDrivingGear.isHidden = true
            chooseBox1.isHidden = false                        

        }
}
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return drivingGear[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return drivingGear.count
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        chooseDrivingGear.isHidden = false
        chooseDrivingGear2.isHidden = false
        chooseDrivingGear3.isHidden = false
        chooseDrivenGear1.isHidden = false
        chooseDrivenGear2.isHidden = false
        chooseDrivenGear3.isHidden = false

        return false
    }
```

Comment: Where have you defined 'row' ?

Comment: I have this if statement if this is where i am defined it because otherwise i just have the regular functions to create a pickerview.

if pickerView.tag == 0 {
 chooseBox1.setTitle(drivingGear[row], for: .normal) 
 chooseDrivingGear.isHidden = true
 chooseBox1.isHidden = false
}

Comment: Can you add the code snippet where you actually get the picker value? Because in your current post, there is no code for pickerView. Because based on your code and try, we can help you out.

Comment: I have added my other code for my picker view, thanks.

Comment: While this does not answer your question, I suggest using [ActionSheetPicker 3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0). I use it a lot, it's simple and works well. *(no affiliation)*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try getting the `selectedRow` from both the `pickerViews`, get the values for the selected rows and the perform calculation on the values as required to show in the `textField`.

I have provided a sample code for that below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView2: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    let drivingGear = ["1", "12", "36", "60", "84"]

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func showResult(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let val1 = self.drivingGear[self.pickerView1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        let val2 = self.drivingGear[self.pickerView2.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        if let intVal1 = Int(val1), let intVal2 = Int(val2)
        {
            let result = intVal1 / intVal2
            self.textField.text = String(result)
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.drivingGear.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
        return self.drivingGear[row]
    }
}
```

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: the showResult function...is that something that i have to create in addition to the functions I already have? or can i throw what you have inside in my chooseBox1 function? if not, am i supposed to control drag the textbox to create that function?

Comment: After both picker views have a selected value i want the textField to show the result.

Comment: Then create a button `Show Result` and on the button click event, show the result in textField. This is what `showResult` method does.

Comment: I did this @IBAction func showResultBox1(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let val1 = self.drivingGear[self.chooseDrivingGear.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        let val2 = self.drivingGear[self.chooseDrivenGear1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        if let intVal1 = Int(val1), let intVal2 = Int(val2) {
            let result = intVal1 / intVal2
            
            self.title = String(result)
        }
        resultBox1.isHidden = false
    }

Comment: But it doesn't change the button to show the calculation